# Load related data with EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linqkit

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug in EF Core 3.1 but the following works with EF 6.x and is part of a Generic Repository which I'm converting to EF Core 3.1:

```
  IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.Context.Set<TEntity>();

  if (filter != null)
  {
      query = query.AsExpandable().Where(filter);
  }

  if (includeProperties != null)
  {
      foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new[] { ',' },
                                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
      {
          query = query.Include(includeProperty);
      }
  }
```

but it doesn't work in EF Core 3.1

I've tried changing my "Roles" properties from `virtual` to a regular public property but no change and the weird thing is that if I call the following code in my data layer before call the above code:

```
var test = this.Context
               .Users
               .Include(u => u.Roles)
               .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Username == "xxx@xxx.com");
```

it works as expected and then if I execute the problematic code, it loads my roles as expected.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more [LinqKit `AsExpandable` problem](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/issues/14), although is caused by strange EF Core requirement which LinqKit is failing/not willing to implement even in its EF Core dedicated version [LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore).

The problem is that LinqKit uses its own query provider, but EF Core ignores `Include` and some other EF Core queryable extensions if the query provider is not what they expect (class derived from `EntityQueryProvider`).

The workaround is to move all EF Core specific methods like `Include`,  `ThenInclude`, `AsNoTracking` etc. **before** `AsExpandable`. Or don't use `AsExpandable` at all, call manually `Expand()` on expressions which need it, e.g. instead of

```
    query = query.AsExpandable().Where(filter);
```

use

```
    query = query.Where(filter.Expand());
```

Comment: Worked a charmed!! Started process of dumping my Generic Repository and use specific one instead as I read info that it wasn't great and overkill to have one but I must say, I really like what I've done so far and was feeling blah having to dump it but won't have to now! Thanks so much for that!